# Slaughtering with a non-kosher knife לכתחילה (Rashi, חולין דף ח ע״ב)

Tags: rashi, chulin-tractate

*Rashi* to *Chulin* 8 *amud* 2 takes the unusual step of mentioning the practical *halacha* that he derived from the *g'mara*. He says that, because the *g'mara* came to no conclusion about what to do with an animal slaughtered with a non-kosher (taken from a non-Jew) knife, one must deal with the carcass according to the stricter of the two opinions in the *g'mara*. He then adds that, because the *g'mara* had asked only what to do if someone already slaughtered with such a knife, one may not slaughter with such a knife.

How does this ruling fit with the passage on *amud* 1 on which *Rav Nachman* says one may slaughter with such a knife?

Comment: Rashi's ruling seems reasonable at first glance, since it's presupposed by two amora'im that it's forbidden, one of whom is Rav (and הלכה כרב באיסורי)